# SFDX: exports.getOrgApiVersion is not a function

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error

I am trying to retrieve source from org using SFDX and VSC.

When I run the command I get an error:

```
18:51:03.608 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

exports.getOrgApiVersion is not a function
```

Using Macbook Pro M2 if that's relevant.

Comment: Did you try updating your Salesforce CLI version?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira - yes, it's updated :(

Comment: Maybe you are running an outdated version of the extension in VSC, or not running the command from within a valid Salesforce DX project.

Comment: I am having the same issue today with an existing project that was working fine last night.  It happens when I try to retrieve source. I updated the CLI, which did update, but did not fix the issue.  I have a second project that gave me the same issue.

Comment: This issue is being reported (multiple times) on the SFDX for VSCode repo: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4936

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved v58.3.1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue appears to relate to the update to the Salesforce CLI Integration extension released 6/21/2023, version 58.3.0. I rolled back to version 58.2.0 and the issue has disappeared.

You can do this by

- Navigating to the VSCode Extensions,
- Clicking into the Salesforce CLI Integration extension,
- Clicking the Down Arrow beside "Uninstall,"
- Clicking "Install Another Version...,"
- Then selecting version 58.2.0 and reloading.

EDIT: Salesforce has released a patch, version 58.3.1, that also fixes this issue; you can now fully upgrade to the latest version of the extension to fix the issue. I had to navigate to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core and click "Install" to get VSCode to recognize a patch was available.

Comment: You saved me from disaster. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works!

Comment: I've been using v55.8.0 for several months now because of similar errors to this. Hopefully Salesforce can get a stable build released at some point so we can take advantage of features in the latest builds.

Comment: If you use the `npm` version of sfdx-cli, you can rollback with this command `npm install -g sfdx-cli@7.204.6`

Answer (score 0):

Update the Salesforce CLI by the following command in the terminal:

```
SFDX Update
```

Then follow these steps:

1. Click on the drop-down menu near "Uninstall" in the Salesforce CLI Integration.
2. Select "Install Another Version." Install version 58.0.1.
3. After successful installation, reload Visual Studio Code.
4. The issue should be resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to roll back the extension pack and all of its components to 58.2.0
Worked fine after that